# Can not connect my ASP.net Core app to elasticsearch using serilog

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, serilog

i want to use serilog.sinks.elasticsearch to log my data in the elasticsearch, i installed these packages:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" Version="8.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="5.1.1" />
```

and here is what i did:

1: i pulled kibana and elasticsearch image and use docker compose file to run them together,
here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:8.5.0
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - xpack.monitoring.templates.enabled
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled= false
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: kibana:8.5.0
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - elastic


networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

and my appsetings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Hangfire": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ElasticConfiguration": {
      "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/360-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is my program class:

```
ConfigureLogging();
builder.Host.UseSerilog();


void ConfigureLogging()
{
    var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile(
            $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
            optional: true)
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithEnvironmentName()
        .WriteTo.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(ConfigureElasticSink(configuration, environment!))
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", environment!)
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
}

ElasticsearchSinkOptions ConfigureElasticSink(IConfigurationRoot configuration, string environment)
{
    return new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
        IndexFormat = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{environment?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}"
    };
}
```

the problem is here that elasticsearch can not find my application to recive the data from it.

is there any thing else that i should add or is there any mistake in my code?